# The word or phrase to send a message, knowing that it's being eavesdropped on/leaked, to trap the eavesdropper/leaker?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

Let's say I'm the boss of an organisation, and I think one of my executives is a mole for a rival organisation.  One way to test this out is to give a different bit of (fake) information to each of my executives.  Each piece of information should be devised so that if it reaches the hands of my rivals I can tell somehow, by their subsequent actions.

I sit back and wait to see which bit of fake info is acted upon by the rival organisation, and I then know which of my executives is the mole:  the one to which I gave that particular bit of information.

Does this technique/tactic have a name?  A "*something*-trap" perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps  "mole  trap": Mole - 

​
a person who works for an organization or government and secretly gives information to its competitor or enemy:

Comment: In the world of espionage, ***honey traps*** and ***false flags*** are relevant terms.

Comment: Your scenario certainly sounds like a surreptitious trap. Arguably, most traps are surreptitious by nature, but hey, I kinda like the word "surreptitious"! More simply, however, what you have is a spy. spying on a spy. Wasn't there a regular feature in Mad Magazine years ago titled "Spy vs. Spy"?

Comment: Tom Clancy invented the term ['canary trap'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_trap) for this; the linked article says the term in intelligence circles is 'barium meal test'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it might be "honey trap" - this is when an irresistible, but false, bait is provided which fits the description.  I don't think "false flag" is right, as that refers to carrying out an action while pretending to be an agent of a different organisation (originally, attacking a ship while flying the flag of an enemy country, to provoke conflict).

Comment: @StoneyB I think your comment about the "Barium Meal test" is the best answer. although that wikipedia page doesn't explain the origin of the "Barium Meal" name (I suppose it's from medicine, where a barium meal is used to track where the food goes, in an x-ray).  if you want to write it up into an answer I'll mark it as correct, thanks.

Comment: I suggest that no, there is no specific name for that, nor anything like it.

I don't remember what *false flags* means butt a *honey trap* is completely different. Broadly, a *honey trap* is when an agent - almost always a woman agent - seduces a target. How could that matter here, please?